# Exception:java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [D

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have logistic regression model and I want to calculating recall@25

```
val predictionAndLabels = predicted
.select("prediction", "label")
.rdd.map(x => (x(0).asInstanceOf[Array[Double]], x(1)
.asInstanceOf[Array[Double]]))
val matrix = new RankingMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
 Array(1, 25).foreach { k =>
  println(s"Recall at $k = ${matrix.RecallAt(k)}")
}
```

this exception appear

> java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [D

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

RankingMetrics requires RDD(array, array) where as you are having RDD(double,double) which means you are passing the **INVALID** arguments.

In General for Type conversion, map transformation used

**Assuming that predictionAndLabels.rdd type is RDD(double,double)**

**pairArrRDD = predictionAndLabels.rdd.map(x => (Array(x._1),Array(x._2)))** //this is in scala

val matrix = new RankingMetrics(**pairArrRDD**)

Comment: thanks alot, but value recallAt is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RankingMetrics[Double].